# Local Extrema of Function & Supremum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Let $f(x, y) :=−3x^4−y^2+ 4x^2y$.

Prove that, for any $v∈R^2$, the function $h_v:R→R$ given by $h_v(t):=f(tv)$ has a local maximum at t= 0.  Then find all local extrema of f, as well as $sup_{R^2} f$ and $inf_{R^2} f$.

To find the local maximum, i will have to find partial second order derivative for f(x,y) but is this the same as f(tv)? I know that If f has a local max or min at a then for h the function g(t)=f(a + th) has a
local max or min at t = 0, but i dont know how to prove that.

In addition, how owuld i find all local extrema, sup and inf?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you proved that $ h_v $ has a local maximum at $ t=0 $?

Comment: This is an infamous example. Before you proceed to the final questions, note that you can factor $f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 2):

To show that $ h_v $ has a local maximum at $ 0 $ it is enough to calculate 
    $ h_v'(0) $ and $ h_v''(0) $ (along with checking a special case).
Next notice that a necessary condition for (a,b) to be a local extrema is that 
 $$ \left. \frac{d}{dx} f(x,y) \right|_{(x,y)=(a,b)} 
= \left. \frac{d}{dy} f(x,y) \right|_{(x,y)=(a,b)} = 0. $$
This is enough to determine all local extrema.
Finally to find sup and inf consider the functions $ x\mapsto f(x,0) $ and $ x\mapsto f(x,2x^2) $.

Comment: i got h''<0 and h'=0 so t=0 is local max but what do you meanby special case

Comment: if special case is y=0, how do i prove it is still local max

Comment: The special case is indeed $ v = (v_1,0) $. In this case though $ h_v(tv) = -3v_1^4t^4 $ and we can observe that $ h_v(t) \leq 0 $ for all $ t \in \mathbb{R} $ with equality only when $ t=0 $.

Comment: got it thanks! and for the sup and inf two functions you suggested both go to negative infinity? so that is the inf but what is the sup? thanks

Comment: I got that $ f(x,2x^2) = -3x^4 - 4x^4 + 4x^2\cdot 2x^2 = x^4 $ so sup is $ +\infty $. It is easier to see what to try if you as @Ted suggested first factorize it as $ f(x,y) = -(y-x^2)(y-3x^2) $.